# How to create a button and locate it on a panel based on user input

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton, form-layout

In first frame, I have a panel with form layout, I have a "ADD" button. When user click ADD button, a second frame will shown. Second frame is shown to allow user to fill the information needed to create a button in A.java.

**ADD button on frame of A.java:**

```
JButton button_3 = new JButton("ADD");//ADD ROW
    button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addCHECKUP addC = new addCHECKUP();//note that addCHECKUP is B.java
            addC.setVisible(true);
            addC.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        }

    });
```

**frame of A.java:**

[image]

If user click ADD button at **frame of A.java**, **frame of B.java** will be shown.

**frame of B.java:**

[image]

After user finish in giving all the input at frame of B.java, ADD button will be clicked. Then a new button is created at frame of A.java based on user input at frame of B.java.

So far, when ADD button at frame of B.java is clicked, the information is saved into a text file. Below is the ADD button code.

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("ADD");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            System.out.println(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem());   //getActivity

             if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){//if complication
                System.out.println("*"+textField.getText());//setTaskName have * sign
                }
            else{
                System.out.println(textField.getText());    
                }
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());  //getDay

              String filename = "c:" + File.separator + "Text File from B.java Class.txt";
                File f = new File(filename);
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {

                    pw = new PrintWriter(f);                
                    pw.println(comboBox_1.getSelectedItem());
                    if (chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected()){//if complication
                        pw.println("*"+textField.getText());

                        }
                    else{
                        pw.println(textField.getText());

                        }
                    pw.println(comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                    pw.flush();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{

                    if(pw!=null){
                        pw.close();
                    }

            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successfully added !");
        }
    });
```

Now, I intend to access the text file and create a new button based on the information from text file. I don't know how to make the new button based on the information from the text file. If there is any other method that more easier, please let me know.

I want to create button like this: I put this at B.java

```
JButton btn_34 = new JButton("Uptitrate BB");//Task Name
BigPanel.add(btn_34, "12, 11");  //12 and 11 is based on Activity and Day
```

**But error in BigPanel.add**

Comment: You have another problem whenever you click on add button you are going to over write the same file. Why are you not using a Database?

Comment: @Blip I'm not using Database because this is just for a prototype only, not the real software.. I don't know how to connect the user input with create a new button. Plus, this project use 2 classes, and I don't know how to connect between A.java and B.java classes.

Comment: could you post the actionlistner of the frame A.java showing how it is initialising and calling the frame B.java?

Comment: @Blip Sorry for the inconvenience, I have edited it just now

Comment: I would suggest that you use `JDialog` instead of `JFrame` for B.java. That way you could return results from B.java and also make A.java non editable while B.java is showing.

Comment: @Blip I will try JDialog and see how it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Properties read and write this.

So all you need are keys and values.

```
final Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("Activity", comboBox_1.getSelectedItem());
prop.setProperty("Complication", chckbxNewCheckBox.isSelected());
prop.setProperty("Day", comboBox.getSelectedItem());
writePropertyIntoFile("c:" + File.separator + "Text File from B.java   Class.txt", prop);
```

And your write method may look like this

```
private static void writePropertyIntoFile(String file, final Properties prop)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (final FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);) {
        prop.store(f, null);
    }
}
```

Sincerely

**Update-1**

I assume I have a property File containing

```
B1.Day,1
B1.Complication,true
B1.Activity,Diagnose
B2.Day,2
B2.Complication,false
B2.Activity,Labs
B3.Day,5
B3.Complication,false
B3.Activity,Oxygon
```

Now, I only need to loop over all Bs an call createButton for each containing in this property file. All I may save is the last used index. So if the user adds a new one. We create a new Button Bn. Save this in the file and you are done.

**Update-2**

```
JButton button_3 = new JButton("ADD");//ADD ROW
button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String btName = getNextFreeButtonName();
        Button btnX = createNewButton("Oxy", "11","10", btName);
        mapContainingAllButtons.put(btName, btnX)
        addButtonToFram(btnX);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my main problem is to create a new button based on user input which are Activity(Row), Day(Column), Task name(Button name) and Complication(put * sign or not at task name) . Do you know how to connect new JButton and the Properties?

Comment: Do you need a property for each Button?

Comment: Of course, because, to create a new button, I have to set the button name and position of the button(row-activity&column-day)

Comment: Actually you could use one Properties file for all buttons. All you need is a prefix within the key like "B1.Day" and then you can access all attributes.

Comment: Can you show me how to create new button using the Properties?

Comment: Okay that is the content of file... So how about a coding for create new button? For eg :    ' JButton btn_21 = new JButton("Pulse oximetry ");
  btn_21.addActionListener(deleteAction);
  BigPanel.add(btn_21, "2, 6");'   @Christian